# Shell scipt or python script to convert the time into human readable format

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, shell

I have a time in the format like **20170103154828 pwcg12.apache.web 39558809870** from a log but i would like to see it in the human readable format **2017-01-03 15:48:28 pwcg12.apache.web 39558809870** . Since it is not a epoch time and generated by the server , so applying epoch conversion will not work on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just extract the parts of the string with substring operations, and then connect them with `-` and `:`.

Comment: `datetime.strftime` and `datetime.strptime` FTW https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice that it's just a human-readable time without those punctuation characters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: i imported the time and used strftime but it didn't work in converting it.

Comment: Define "didn't work", show your code and any error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple not complicated at all way to accomplish this.

```
time = "20170103154828"

first = time[:4] + '-' + time[4:]
second = first[:7] + '-' + first[7:]
third = second[:10] + ' ' + second[10:]

hour = third[:13] + ':' + third[13:]
final = hour[:16] + ':' + hour[16:]
print(final)
```

Yields:

```
2017-01-03 15:48:28
```